# Showing content only to Tumblr blog owner/admin

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

Is there a way to determine whether the current user is the admin of the blog? Something like

```
{Block:Owner}
    This is your blog. Click here to update the theme settings.
{/Block:Owner}
```

Even something via javascript/API would be helpful. I couldn't find anything in the [theme documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)

Answer (score 3):

I found a way, but it's not completely reliable and it depends on the language and possibly the OS.

The Tumblr controls bar's size varies in the 3 possible situations:

[image: not logged in] 261x**36** not logged in (this depends on the blog's name)

[image: admin] 190x26 logged in, admin

[image: not admin] 179x26 logged in, but no admin

So we can sort of figure out if the user is logged in with this code:

```js
//true: the current user is an admin
//false: the current user is not an admin
//'ask-later': the bar is not ready yet
//'dont-know': the bar is not there 
function isAdmin (tolerance) {
    // source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27506229/288906

    //these values are expected for English blogs
    var EXPECTED_WIDTH = 190;
    var EXPECTED_HEIGHT = 26;

    tolerance = tolerance || 10;
    var controls = document.getElementById('tumblr_controls');
    if(!controls) {
        //the bar is not there
        return 'dont-know';
    }
    if(controls.width === '1') {
        //the bar is not ready, try later
        return 'ask-later';
    }
    var differenceW = Math.abs(controls.width - EXPECTED_WIDTH)
    var differenceH = Math.abs(controls.height - EXPECTED_HEIGHT);
    return differenceW + differenceH < tolerance;
}
```

With `tolerance` we can specify a range of values that can still be considered acceptable, so 195x28 can still work. This code doesn't work on password-protected blogs since they don't show that bar.

This could be improved further by making it async with promises, so you can avoid that "not yet ready" state.

Comment: This would need to be modified for sideblogs as when you are logged in and viewing them, you have the option to follow and edit theme.